# <ion-searchbar> is not working inside <ion-header> Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I m working with Ionic 4 and I'm trying to implement a searchbar into the header just like this :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <!-- Side menu button-->
    <ion-buttons slot="start">

      <button (click)="openFirst()"><img src="../../../assets/jas.png"></button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title><ion-searchbar ></ion-searchbar></ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

My problem is that the search bar displays but I can't write anything inside.

Also, when it's not inside `<ion-title>`, it's not working.

It seems that it is working in every other place of the app

Comment: tryed your code worked fine in chrome for me, was what platform you testing on ?

Comment: The `<ion-buttons>` was the problem for me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this as follows,

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Enter Place</ion-title> 
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionInput)="updateSearch()" (ionCancel)="dismiss()"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionInput)="updateSearch()" (ionCancel)="dismiss()">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: I will. I have to wait 10mns

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you share why one needs to add ion searchbar twice? Is it a workaround for a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 5, you could do somehting like:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-tootlbar>
    <ion-title>My Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

Each new sibling of ion-toolbar will appear as a new line.

This also works if you are trying to use this with collapse=condense, inside ion-content.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-buttons>
       <ion-title>`enter title here`</ion-title>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).